# How to declare a dictionary using String as key, and Arrays of Ints as value in Swift language?

Tags: swift

How do I declare a dictionary using String as key, and containing Arrays as value in Swift?

This won't work:

```
var unloadedImagesRows:[String:[Int]()]! = [String:[Int]()]()
```

Comment: This seems to work:     var unloadedImagesRows:[String:[Int]]! = [String:[Int]]()
... but the doc says [Int]() is the way to declare arrays in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly declare the type of the variable. Swift is often smart enough to infer the type from its value.

Try this:

```
var unloadedImagesRows = [String: [Int]]()
unloadedImagesRows["array1"] = [1,2,3,4]
unloadedImagesRows["array2"] = [5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
var unloadedImagesRows:[String:[Int]]! = [String:[Int]]()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var unloadedImagesRows:[String: [Int]] = ["somekey": [1,2,3]]
```

or for an empty dictionary

```
var unloadedImagesRows:[String: [Int]] = [ : ]
```